# displaying lists in custom SharePoint Online Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I am currently working on and experimenting with SharePoint Online and the content which it provides. I discovered this tutorial [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part#:%7E:text=%20Preview%20the%20web%20part%20in%20SharePoint%27s%20hosted,web%20parts%20available%20on%20the%20site...%20More%20) which details the process of creating a custom webpart. I commented on the training previously but I was only given a sample that doesn't work, at least from my pov, with the method established here.

This is all fine and dandy if I wanted to do theses separately but I would also like to do more with the webpart than just show the names of lists. Particularly I want to show the contents of them. Does anyone know how exactly this might be done?

I haven't really deviated from the code, and its all listed in the tutorial but if you'd like to see it, let me know and I will edit this post.

Thank you all in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

@Mia P,

Do you want to display list items from a SharePoint online list in a SPFx webart? If so, please taka a reference below sample:

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/js-display-list/README.md

[image]

BR

Comment: Here's the thing, I did look at this demo before but I'm not really sure how it's supposed to work with the aforementioned method, that's sorta what the question is if these are to be utilized together how can that be done?

Comment: @Baker_Kon_MSFT please see above